# Where is Bluetooth connection data stored on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller

I'm trying to find a way to connect a PS4 controller via Bluetooth to my PC. The issue I'm having is that on Windows 10 you can't attempt a connection using the pairing code like you could with W7. W10 forces you to connect the standard way with it trying to get a response from the controller. Problem is, while the controller is detected by windows, the controller isn't designed to be able to respond as far as I know, causing a connection failure. So, I was thinking I'd create my own connection file based off of another, but I have no idea where to put it. Also is this even possible, or should I give up and go back to W7?

Answer (score 1):

see the LEName or Name REG_BINARY you'll see the name of the devices
in Windows Registry Editor

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`

Pairing keys (link keys) for each paired device, associated with their MAC addresses
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`